# Finding index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

All was well with this program until I made some changes in my addMainMenu method. Now it seems as though there is an array index out of bounds somewhere. Eclipse is not leading me too it. Does anyone know why this code has an array index out of bounds exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Menu.main(Menu.java:58)
```

---

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Menu {
    LinkedList <LinkedList> mainMenuItems = new LinkedList <LinkedList> ();

    public void  Menu(){}

    public boolean addMainMenuItem(String newItem, String existingItem, int position){
        LinkedList <String> subMenuItems = new LinkedList <String> ();
        for (int i = 0; i<= mainMenuItems.size(); i++){
            if (mainMenuItems.get(i).contains(existingItem)){
                subMenuItems.addLast(newItem);
                int existingIndex = mainMenuItems.indexOf(existingItem);
                if (position == 1){
                    mainMenuItems.add(existingIndex + 1, subMenuItems);
                    break;
                }
                if (position == -1){
                    mainMenuItems.add(existingIndex, subMenuItems);
                    break;
                }
                if (i == mainMenuItems.size()){
                    subMenuItems.addLast(newItem);
                    mainMenuItems.add(subMenuItems);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean deleteMainMenuItem(String item){
    if (mainMenuItems.contains(mainMenuItems.indexOf(item))){
        mainMenuItems.remove(mainMenuItems.indexOf(item));
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Menu b = new Menu();
    b.addMainMenuItem("h", "b", 1);
    b.addMainMenuItem("hi", "h", 1);
    b.addMainMenuItem("i", "h", 1);
    System.out.println(b.mainMenuItems.get(0));
    b.deleteMainMenuItem("hi");
    System.out.println(b.mainMenuItems.get(0));
    System.out.println(b.deleteMainMenuItem("hi"));
}
```

Comment: are you sure of this line  LinkedList <LinkedList> mainMenuItems = new LinkedList <LinkedList> ();? LinkedList type LinedList?

Comment: A linkedlist that takes a linked list

Comment: Eclipse doesn't just show that the error is somewhere, it outputs the exact line where it occured. Please include the full error message or take a look at it by yourself and you will see where it happened.

Comment: No it keeps leading me to the same error after making more changes

Comment: I fixed your code formatting... it was really ugly, please respect the people trying to help you. Nonetheless, it's still difficult to understand. Refactor this code, rename your parameters, do something to make your code readable and understandable, add some comments, make it object oriented (what the hell is this 1/-1 position flag ?), try not to use breaks in loops... read "clean code"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are two possible issues**

**1**. In this line

```
for (int i = 0; i<= mainMenuItems.size(); i++)
```

you should have use `i < mainMenuItems.size()`

**2**. when you have not assigned any value to your LinkedList, you try to access an index of your LinkedList

Answer (score 1):

Change the `<=` to `<` in: `i<= mainMenuItems.size()`

**EDIT:**
If `mainMenuItems` is still empty, the line `mainMenuItems.get(i).contains(existingItem)` will generate `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` because `mainMenuItems.get(i)` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Dave See the addition to the answer

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.LinkedList.get(Unknown Source)
 at Menu.main(Menu.java:60)

Comment: for some reason it does not allow my print messages

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure who you responded to, did you see the "edit" ?

Comment: @Dave I think your problem is from your add function

Comment: it is I am slowly figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

First - Change the for loop as shown below

```
for (int i = 0; i < mainMenuItems.size(); i++)
```

Also, you need to restructure addMainMenuItem method as shown below -

```
for (int i = 0; i < mainMenuItems.size(); i++){
    if (mainMenuItems.size() == 0) {
        //you should put list initialization code here
        //means, logic when there is nothing in the mainMenuItems list
    } else {
        //when the list is not empty
    }
}
```

You are getting IndexOutOfBoundsException because you are doing get(index) on mainMenuItems - which is empty in your for loop.

For example -

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.get(0);    //will throw the same exception
```